# how to make cocos creator touch listener

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I started to learn cocos a few days ago and I don't really understand how to use the eventListener, I tried to copy the example code in their documentation website and make it so that instead of moving with the WASD keys you'll move by touching the screen, I tried to add it to the code but it didn't work... this is my code

```
    cc.Class({
    extends: cc.Component,

    properties: {
        // foo: {
        //     // ATTRIBUTES:
        //     default: null,        // The default value will be used only 
   when the component attaching
        //                           // to a node for the first time
        //     type: cc.SpriteFrame, // optional, default is typeof default
        //     serializable: true,   // optional, default is true
        // },
        // bar: {
        //     get () {
        //         return this._bar;
        //     },
        //     set (value) {
        //         this._bar = value;
        //     }
        // },
    },
    // Player.js
    //...
    properties: {
        // main character's jump height
        jumpHeight: 0,
        // main character's jump duration
        jumpDuration: 0,
        // maximal movement speed
        maxMoveSpeed: 0,
        // acceleration
        accel: 0,
    },
    //...

    setJumpAction: function jump() {
        // jump up
        var jumpUp = cc.moveBy(this.jumpDuration, cc.p(0, 
this.jumpHeight)).easing(cc.easeCubicActionOut());
        // jump down
        var jumpDown = cc.moveBy(this.jumpDuration, cc.p(0, - 
this.jumpHeight)).easing(cc.easeCubicActionIn());
        // repeat
        return cc.sequence(jumpUp, jumpDown);
    },

    setInputControl: function () {
        var self = this;
        // add keyboard event listener
        // When there is a key being pressed down, judge if it's the 
designated directional button and set up acceleration in the corresponding 
direction
        cc.systemEvent.on(cc.SystemEvent.EventType.KEY_DOWN, function 
(event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case cc.KEY.a:
                    self.accLeft = true;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.d:
                    self.accRight = true;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.w:
                    self.accUp = true;
                    break;
            }
        });

        // when releasing the button, stop acceleration in this direction
        cc.systemEvent.on(cc.SystemEvent.EventType.KEY_UP, function (event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case cc.KEY.a:
                    self.accLeft = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.d:
                    self.accRight = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.w:
                    self.accUp = false;
                    break;
            }
        });
    },

    setTouchControl: function () {
        //Create a "one by one" touch event listener (processes one touch at a time)
        var listener1 = cc.EventListener.create({
            event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
            // When "swallow touches" is true, then returning 'true' from the onTouchBegan method will "swallow" the touch event, preventing other listeners from using it.
            swallowTouches: true,
            //onTouchBegan event callback function                     
            onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {
                var x = touch.getLocationX();
                var y = touch.getLocationY();
            },
            //Trigger when moving touch
            onTouchMoved: function (touch, event) {
                //Move the position of current button sprite
                var x = touch.getLocationX();
                var y = touch.getLocationY();
            },
            //Process the touch end event
            onTouchEnded: function (touch, event) {
                var x = touch.getLocationX();
                var y = touch.getLocationY();
            }
        });
        cc.systemEvent.addListener(listener1, this.node);
        cc.systemEvent.on(cc.SystemEvent.EventType.KEY_UP, function (event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case cc.KEY.a:
                    self.accLeft = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.d:
                    self.accRight = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.w:
                    self.accUp = false;
                    break;
            }
        });
    },

    // Player.js
    onLoad: function () {
        // initialize jump action
        this.jumpAction = this.setJumpAction();
        this.node.runAction(this.jumpAction);

        // switch of acceleration direction
        this.accLeft = false;
        this.accRight = false;
        this.accUp = false;
        // current horizontal speed of main character
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = 0;

        // initialize keyboard input listener
        this.setInputControl();

        this.setTouchControl();
    },

    // LIFE-CYCLE CALLBACKS:

    // onLoad () {},

    start() {

    },

    // update (dt) {},

    // Player.js
    update: function (dt) {
        // update speed of each frame according to the current acceleration direction
        if (this.accLeft) {
            this.xSpeed -= this.accel * dt;
        } else if (this.accRight) {
            this.xSpeed += this.accel * dt;
        }
        // restrict the movement speed of the main character to the maximum movement speed
        if (Math.abs(this.xSpeed) > this.maxMoveSpeed) {
            // if speed reaches its limit, use the max speed with current direction
            this.xSpeed = this.maxMoveSpeed * this.xSpeed / Math.abs(this.xSpeed);
        }

        // update the position of the main character according to the current speed
        this.node.x = this.x;
    },
});
```

I tried to use the function setTouchControl for my porpuses but I don't even know if it's good and if so how to use it in code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found the answer... here:

```
properties: {
},
onLoad () {

    this.node.on('touchstart', function(){

    }, this.node);

    this.node.on('touchmove', function (event) {

        var delta = event.touch.getDelta();

        this.x += delta.x;
        this.y += delta.y;

    }, this.node);

    this.node.on('touchend', function () {
    }, this.node);
},
```

Comment: It works when put this code on Game.js but not work with Player.js.